Can't load Css file in Jsp Page
I'm trying to connect CSS with the JSP page. I wrote like this `
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/plugins.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">`

in spring-servlet.xml
 <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

I wrote like this but if I write these codes I get 404 not found an error . if I remove these codes error is gone
I'm trying to connect the CSS file in JSP
usually, I write like this 

  somebody help me.....please...


The code requires <c:url> tag to be defined.

Example usage:
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

<html>
   <head>
   </head>

   <body>
      <a href = "<c:url value = "/jsp/index.htm"/>">TEST</a>
   </body>
</html>

